# Singleton HttpClient calling GetAsync/SendAsync with async/await never returns

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, xamarin.android, dotnet-httpclient

I am building an application using Xamarin (Android), it uses a PCL project as a Service layer. I have a Web Api endpoint and I am using `HttpClient` to consume it.

Everything works fine, but if I leave my Android app open and idle for a while (like 2 minutes) and I try to make a new request, the first request using the singleton `HttpClient` won't work. It just never returns and stays there until it timeouts (`TaskCancelledException`). I also put a breakpoint on my Api and it doesn't get hit. If I try to send the request again, then it works.

After a lot of debugging I found that this only happens if I try to use the `HttpClient` as a Singleton. If I create a new `HttpClient` for every request everything works.

At first I thought this was a deadlock issue, I've done a lot of research and double checked everything following the guidelines described in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343632/httpclient-getasync-never-returns-when-using-await-async) and [Stephen Cleary's excellent post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and I'm almost sure this is not the case.
I'm using `ConfigureAwait(false)` in every call from my PCL project so it doesn't capture the context.

### The flow of a request goes like this:

Inside an Android Fragment:

```
SampleService svc = new SampleService();
response = await svc.GetAllSamples();
```

The service called (in my PCL project):

```
public class SampleService
{
    public HttpClient Client { get; set; }

    public SampleService()
    {
        // resolves my singleton instance and uses my custom DelegatingHandler
        Client = CustomHttpClient.Instance;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Sample>> GetAllSamples()
    {
        IEnumerable<Sample> list = null;

        // this never returns and timeouts the first time
        using (var response = await Client.GetAsync("samples").ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                lista = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Sample>>(json)).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I build my Singleton instance:

```
public sealed class CustomHttpClient
{
    private static HttpClient _client;

    public static HttpClient GetClient()
    {
        if (_client == null)
        {
            HttpMessageHandler messageHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            _client = new HttpClient(messageHandler);
            _client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            _client.BaseAddress = new Uri("myendpoint");
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }

        return _client;
    }
}
```

I tried to simplify and isolate the code here, if I can provide any other useful snippets, just let me know.

Am I doing something wrong regarding singletons `HttpClient` that I'm not aware of?

**Update:** Just for clarification, I'm trying to use `HttpClient` as a Singleton just because, as I found in [this answer by Darrel Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20075006/1710624) and in the book [Designing Evolvable Web APIs with ASP.NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449337716) (Chapter 14), they were designed to be reusable and thread-safe (in most of the cases). From my research I'm not using anything that is not thread-safe in it.

Comment: Well you're not disposing of the responses, for one thing. I'm not sure whether HttpClient is *meant* to be used like this though... any reason you don't want to create a new one for each request?

Comment: At first I wasn't using it as a Singleton, but as Darrel Miller suggests, `HttpClient` can be reused (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074580/is-my-implementaton-of-httpclient-singleton-appropriate). Also stated in this book (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920026617.do chapter 14). It doesn't actually say "Singleton", it just says it can be reused.

Comment: I'm not sure I need to dispose `Response` since every request is a new isolated object and it *should be* thread-safe.

Comment: `HttpResponseMessage` implements `IDisposable`, so you should dispose it. This may very well be the problem - it certainly would be for `HttpResponse`, where not disposing of a response would basically leave a connection in the connection pool "taken" until it was finalized. It's dead easy for you to dispose of the response here, so isn't it at least worth trying?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @JonSkeet, I'll try this as soon as I get back and report here.

Comment: @JonSkeet I edited my answer disposing the response, I still get the same results

Comment: Coming back to the "Singleton": there is a chance that `HttpClient` does not work as expected on Android. It is a reimplementation using Mono and not the original .NET version. So why not give it a try and recreate the client if you need it? It really doesn't add a lot of overhead. 99% of all time will be spent in the actual request anyway, that's your bottleneck. If you find it behave differently on Mono vs. .NET, go ahead and file a bug at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: [This](https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/HttpClient/0.6.0/Release/.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/System/Net/Http/HttpContent.cs?ImageName=System.Net.Http) is why you want to dispose the response message (check the `Dispose` method)

Comment: I see @YuvalItzchakov, I edited my answer using dispose, unfortunately the issue persists

Comment: @MahmoudAli: Are you actually blocking on the http call at all?

Comment: Yes @StephenCleary, I'm using `await` on my Fragment, and indeed the code is asynchronously waiting. I have a Progress Dialog showing that I omitted in the snippet just for clarity, it is shown while my call is hanging and it goes away on timeout.

Comment: I don't think the advice of re-using `HttpClient` is meant to be taken to such an extreme. It is not an expensive object to create; the benefits are related to re-using the underlying open connection, so if you if you hit the same host many times in a short period of time it may be more efficient to re-use the client. But if your app is sitting idle for 2 minutes between requests, I would absolutely re-instantiate the client. If your app is making relatively few requests in general, you should be just fine creating/disposing the client as needed.

Comment: I'll probably stop using Singletons and I'll make sure I dispose my response objects, as suggested by you guys, but I'm still intrigued by the fact that this fails silently and I don't know the reason :(

Comment: As a side-note, your call to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` seems a little odd. *Usually* there's little point in calling `await Task.Run(...)` - it's CPU-bound work so you're not saving yourself a thead, and you're not doing anything in parallel. So it seems you're just switching threads needlessly there.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @ToddMenier

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Comment: I simply stopped using Singleton, but I did notice that if I ever forget to dispose a response, as Jon Skeet said, it will cause the hanging problem again.

Comment: @MahmoudAli can you link me for the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @jzeferino sorry, it's been so long, I don't have access to this codebase anymore.

Comment: PCL is deprecated, use .NET Standard instead.